# How to move a Google Reader account?

Tags: google-reader, export

Google recently decided that I can't be logged in to my Gmail and Apps accounts at the same time, so I want to move my Google Reader data from one to the other. I know of the "Import/Export feeds" function, but I want to export as much as possible from:

- Feeds
- Starred items
- Trends
- Read/unread status
- Liked items
- Comments

Google must have thought of this when they made the decision, so I suppose there is some way.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you *should* be able to sign into your Gmail and Apps accounts at the same time. Maybe you can try enabling multiple sign-in? https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to transfer starred items. In the old account, go through your starred items, and share them. Log into your new account, and follow the old account's shared items. You can then star those in the new account. Takes some work, but it does work. I did this when I moved my Reader from my GMail account to Google Apps.

As far as I know, Trends is tied to the account and the reading you've done with the account. So you can't move that data.

Comment: Seems like the star -> share -> star approach would be okay for a few items, but after a few dozen it would be horrible. Any ideas on how to maybe script it or automate?

Comment: @mfg As you say, it is no big issue for a small number of items - I had to transfer a few dozen, which took a while. As far as I know Reader does not provide an API, so I don't know how else this could be done.

Answer (score 3):

Tough one:
 - This feature was repeatedly requested on [Google's Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=760df2370ac1a350&hl=en), but no answer from Google
 - On Google's [Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/reader) there is only the import/export solution
 - There is no official API, only reverse engineered ones for [Python](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI), [C#](http://greader.codeplex.com/) or [F#](http://goreader.codeplex.com/) and I couldn't find any program built on these libraries that could do such a thing.

I hope somebody can prove me wrong, but it seems to me that this tool wasn't written yet although the building blocks are there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right in terms of the DLF/API; seems like an OPML export of the feeds won't have 'starred' or 'liked' as some kind of magic standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah they did think about that when they made the transition.

Read [this page](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=182343). I would not transfer my stuff!  Leave it separate and enable multi-log in.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this Lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/#!5602545/how-to-migrate-your-entire-google-account-to-a-new-one):

Update: the part about Google Apps not having Reader is no longer correct so this method should work.

Migrating Google Reader

Here is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja0R_Bxhriw&feature=player_embedded) or the following instructions.

Migrating your RSS feeds is probably the easiest part of this process, but it unfortunately only works with regular Google accounts (since Apps accounts do not have access to Reader). Just go into Google Reader's settings and click on the Import/Export tab. At the bottom, you'll see a link that says "Export Your Subscriptions as an OPML File" which will download a single file to your computer containing all of your feeds. Click on this link, and then go to the same Import/Export tab in Account 2's Settings. This time, click the Choose File button and navigate to the file you just downloaded. After uploading this file, all your feeds should show up in Reader. Note that this won't sync your read and unread counts, nor will it sync your starred or shared articles, so you'll have to re-star anything you still want to reference (and re-friend anyone you follow on Reader).

Answer (score 0):

To approach this from what seems like the cause of the question, have you tried to circumvent the "can't be logged in to my Gmail and Apps accounts at the same time" part of your question?

Since I do not know why you can't log both, I will just try to blindly make suggestions:

- Use two browsers; i.e. Firefox for Reader, et al and Chrome for Apps. You will be able to be logged into both at the same time
- Use a Browser-switching-agent plug-in; I am unsure if this works anymore, but an agent-switcher might be able to mask the fact your are utilizing two accounts from the same browser
- [Use a stand-alone](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/read-me-google-reader-app-for-the-ubuntu-desktop/) [Google Reader client](http://desktopgooglereader.codeplex.com/)
- Use Google Desktop as a reader, or one of the other (awful) desktop toolbars

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I guess I didn't read through your post well enough. What I suggested ended up being what you already knew about and was not looking for. So after reading it a second time it seems like the Multi-log in option would be best. I use that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Google has mutti sign-in

That supports google reader for any type of google account

see: http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?topic=28776

(would copy content in here but theres to much)